# iOS upload photo

Tags: ios, cordova, upload

I am having a problem while trying to upload a photo with my iOS app in Phonegap. The error is:

```
2012-02-16 19:06:17.523 ContactExplorer[851:207] File Transfer Error: Invalid server URL
2012-02-16 19:06:17.623 ContactExplorer[851:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: target)'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01dfb5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01f4f313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01db3ef8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01db3e6a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01df9e15 -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:] + 293
    5   ContactExplorer                     0x00021990 -[PGFileTransfer createFileTransferError:AndSource:AndTarget:] + 153
    6   ContactExplorer                     0x00020c0b -[PGFileTransfer upload:withDict:] + 717
    7   ContactExplorer                     0x000157bf -[PhoneGapDelegate execute:] + 434
    8   ContactExplorer                     0x000029f0 -[AppDelegate execute:] + 80
    9   ContactExplorer                     0x000151e4 -[PhoneGapDelegate executeQueuedCommands] + 265
    10  ContactExplorer                     0x00015291 -[PhoneGapDelegate flushCommandQueue] + 81
    11  ContactExplorer                     0x00015600 -[PhoneGapDelegate webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:] + 822
    12  ContactExplorer                     0x00002d3c -[AppDelegate webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:] + 108
    13  UIKit                               0x00a93a92 -[UIWebView webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:] + 291
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x01d6bc7d __invoking___ + 29
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x01d6bb51 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 145
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x01d99858 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 72
    17  WebKit                              0x0283cc76 -[_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:] + 182
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x01d6ca04 ___forwarding___ + 1124
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x01d6c522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01d6bc7d __invoking___ + 29
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x01d6bb51 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 145
    22  WebCore                             0x03330150 _ZL20HandleDelegateSourcePv + 64
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x01ddc8ff __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x01d3a88b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 571
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x01d39d86 __CFRunLoopRun + 470
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x01d39840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x01d39761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x023781c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x02378289 GSEventRun + 115
    30  UIKit                               0x0090ac93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    31  ContactExplorer                     0x0000246f main + 127
    32  ContactExplorer                     0x000023e5 start + 53
    33  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

I googled the error but there is no description for key:target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read more close:

**[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: target)**

You are trying to set NIL to some dictionary object. We can't find this place in your code using error log.

Check also if you set all arguments properly into objects you're using (several of them you can see in your stack trace). It is possible that exception occurred within some of them.

*** UPDATED:
When I see these lines:

```
5   ContactExplorer                     0x00021990 -[PGFileTransfer createFileTransferError:AndSource:AndTarget:] + 153
6   ContactExplorer                     0x00020c0b -[PGFileTransfer upload:withDict:] + 717
7   ContactExplorer                     0x000157bf -[PhoneGapDelegate execute:] + 434
```

I can suggest than this error was born in PhoneGapDelegate. It uses PGFileTransfer who uses dictionary. And then crash. Some data you provide causing to this. The problem can be also in early realizing of your arguments.

Few lines of code could help. Especially PhoneGap's creation, delegate and custom callbacks.

Comment: I am not so sure this is the case. There is no dictionary object or anything like that in my app. This is a very common error but key has different values

Comment: If you do not use any dictionary explicitly, so see second part of my answer.

Comment: Could you post the code you're using, because I never had that kind of error while trying to upload a file from my PhoneGap/SenchaTouch app.